# How do I retrieve all values for a particular field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data from the Twitter API and I want to retrieve a list of all cities if the countryCode is equal to "AU".

```
{ 
"gnip" : {
    "matching_rules" : [
        {
            "value" : "bio_location: \"Australia\"", 
            "tag" : null
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "bio_location: \"Canberra\"", 
            "tag" : null
        }
    ], 
    "klout_score" : 40, 
    "language" : {
        "value" : "en"
    }, 
    "profileLocations" : [
        {
            "objectType" : "place", 
            "geo" : {
                "type" : "point", 
                "coordinates" : [
                    149.12807, 
                    -35.28346
                ]
            }, 
            "address" : {
                "country" : "Australia", 
                "countryCode" : "AU", 
                "locality" : "Canberra", 
                "region" : "Australian Capital Territory"
            }, 
            "displayName" : "Canberra, Australian Capital Territory, Australia"
        }
    ]
},
```

}

It is important to note here that the distinct() method is not sufficient here since I do not want to have the distinct city names, but each city for each tweet if it is located in Australia.

the output should look like this:
[
Sydney,
Melbourne,
Cranberra
]

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation query returns the distinct city names as aggregation result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    $project: {
        _id: 0, 
        result: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    filtered: { 
                        $filter: { 
                             input: "$gnip.profileLocations", 
                             cond: { 
                                 $eq: [ "$$this.address.countryCode", "AU" ] 
                             }
                        }
                    }
                },
                in: {
                    $setIntersection: [ 
                        { 
                            $map: { 
                                 input: "$$filtered", 
                                 in: "$$this.address.locality"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

The `$filter` aggregation operator is used to select the array data with country code as "AU", and the `$map` is used for getting just the address locality values. The `$setIntersection` is to have the locality names distinct.

Note the aggregation output is always a cursor with document(s). Example output: `{ "result" : [ "Canberra", "Sydney" ] }`.

To get just the array from the output, do this:

```
var agg_output = db.collection.aggregate( // substitute pipeline here from above qyery).toArray()
var output = (agg_output.length > 0) ? agg_output[0].result : [ ]  
// [ "Canberra", "Sydney" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "gnip.profileLocations.address.countryCode": "AU"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$gnip.profileLocations"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "gnip.profileLocations.address.countryCode": "AU"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      results: {
        $addToSet: "$gnip.profileLocations.address.locality"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_In4KjPC-yV)